# Upper bound on chromatic number

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, graph-theory, coloring

Suppose I have a graph $G$ and a function $f:V(G) \to \mathbb{N}$ so that for all $v\in V(G)$ we have:

$$| \{f(v)-f(w)\ge 0 \mid w \in N(v)\} | \le k.$$

Show that the chromatic number $\chi (G) \le k+1$.

I think we can solve this algorithmically; choose the largest numbered vertex $v\in G$ and note that $v$ must have degree at most $k$, so we can color $v$ and its neighbors different colors. I cannot figure out how to continue the algorithm though.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the greedy algorithm, right? The details should be something like this: order the vertices using $ f $, from largest to smallest, say $ v_1 \cdots v_n $. Go through the vertices, coloring $ v_i $ with the smallest color not already used by his neighbors. Now, the only neighbors of his already colored have at least as large $ f$ value, since we are visiting vertices in decreasing $ f $ value. Since there are at maximum $ k $ of those, his color will be at maximum $ k+1 $. This gives the bound on $ \chi(G) $.